# Exhaust memory usage with malloc and sleep in C

Tags: c, memory-management

So I want to exhaust the Windows Memory Usage with a malloc and sleep in C progresively.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't seem to exhaust all the memory usage, I don't know what more to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    while (1) {
        malloc(1024 * 1024);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if your compiler has optimized all the malloc calls?

Comment: You need to actually *write* to the memory.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg gimme an example

Comment: Save the pointer and use write to the memory? You can use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) to write to all of the memory.